# Do i must have capacitors when using L7805CV voltage regulator?

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics

I am creating a small waterpump (5v) controled by arduino.

And i want to reduce voltage from 9v to 5v.

Do i must use capacitors when using L7805CV voltage regulator?[image]

Comment: I fear this is not the right place to ask an electronics question. I suggest to ask on  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ [electronics engineering]. As far as I know the capacitors are necessary to prevent  the 7805  from getting unstable.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: I'm new here, but since this question involves details that are peculiar to Arduino (ref [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/70502/47458)), it seems to me that this is the right place.

Comment: @Seamus The question does not contain any reference to an Arduino in the title not in the text. There is a picture schematic and a UNO tag. But in the comments to the answer you cited the OP states that he/she uses an ESP32.  The question is about electronics; "should I use capacitors on a L7805CV?". I did not vote to close it, I just advised the OP to ask in a forum where the probability of getting a good answer is higher. But that's obsolete now, as there is a usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the datasheet:

https://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf

It's not necessary but I advise to use capacitors on the inputs aswell as on the outputs. It will improve stability.

Another thing: the regulator could get quite warm, depending on how much current the motor consumes.
Why don't you use a 5V power supply? You could power the Arduino with it aswell.

At your schematic you are feeding 9V into the **Vin** pin of the Arduino, this might be a bad idea (I'm not 100% sure), but I think it bypasses the regulator on the Arduino -> it will kill your Arduino.

Comment: The Vin pin is connected to the voltage regulator on the Arduino Uno. It is meant to be provided by a higher voltage, so 9V is ok (as long as the OP doesn't draw too much current through the Arduino). But you are right: Using directly a 5V power supply would save you the voltage regulators.

Comment: Alright. I  was not sure if the Vin bypasses the onboard regulator or not.

Comment: VIN only bypasses the diode that is in series with the barrel jack.

Comment: I think @chrisl 's parenthetical note is the key point here. If the power to drive the motor is the 5V supply regulated on the Arduino, then this is most likely a `bad idea`. The motor should be powered directly from a regulated supply, and not through the Arduino.

Comment: @Seamus The motor is not powered through the Arduino but through extra regulator. Thats ok as long as the regulator can provide the needed current. But as both Arduino and motor run on 5V, the OP could simply use directly a 5V power supply.

Comment: That would be the easiest solution.

Comment: im using esp32 and by this documentation https://docs.zerynth.com/latest/official/board.zerynth.esp32_devkitc/docs/index.html ...it says the Input Voltage is: 7-12V